# Add images to confluence macro

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, macros, confluence

I started to develop and confluence wiki macro but i'm having trouble to get started. I did "hello world" tutorial from their site so everything is up and running.

My problem is that since i'm fairly new to java i can't figure out how to print normal jpeg image on site when the macro is used. It's probably really easy but at this point i might be overthinking this whole thing. So how to show image is browser using java in this case.

Really big thanks for advance and sorry for dumb question.

this is the start, it has useless stuff in it cause its from tutorial.

```
package com.atlassian.tutorial.macro;

import com.atlassian.confluence.content.render.xhtml.ConversionContext;
import com.atlassian.confluence.macro.Macro;
import com.atlassian.confluence.macro.MacroExecutionException;
import com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.component.Scanned;
import com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.imports.ComponentImport;
import com.atlassian.webresource.api.assembler.PageBuilderService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.atlassian.confluence.setup.settings.SettingsManager;

import java.util.Map;

@Scanned
public class helloworld implements Macro {

private SettingsManager settingsManager;
private PageBuilderService pageBuilderService;

@Autowired  
public helloworld(@ComponentImport PageBuilderService pageBuilderService) {
    this.pageBuilderService = pageBuilderService;
}

public void SettingsManager(SettingsManager settingsManager)
{
    this.settingsManager = settingsManager;
}

public String execute(Map<String, String> map, String s, ConversionContext conversionContext) throws MacroExecutionException {

    pageBuilderService.assembler().resources().requireWebResource("com.atlassian.tutorial.myConfluenceMacro:myConfluenceMacro-resources");

    settingsManager

    String baseUrl = settingsManager.getGlobalSettings().getBaseUrl();

    String output = "<div class =\"helloworld\">";
    output = output + "<p>" + baseUrl + "<p>";
    output = output + "<div class = \"" + map.get("Color") + "\">";
    output = output + "<img src="/images/filename.jpeg">";


    if (map.get("Name") != null) {
        output = output + ("<h1>Hello " + map.get("Name") + "!</h1>");
    } else {
        output = output + "<h1>Hello World!<h1>";
    }

    output += "</div></div>";

    return output;
}


public BodyType getBodyType() { return BodyType.NONE; }

public OutputType getOutputType() { return OutputType.BLOCK; }
}
```

Comment: What did you code up to now? Show us some code.

Comment: Make sure the `/images/filename.jpeg` is accessible, otherwise that image will not be displayed.